# Solving system of non-linear equations in two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve the following system of equations

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\|p + \alpha n\| & = &\|q + \beta n\| \\
(p + \alpha n) \cdot (q + \beta n) & = & 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$

for the unknowns $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, with $n$, $p$ and $q$ known vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (the second line contains a dot product), and $\|n\|=1$.

Using some algebra, these equations can be written as

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha^2 - \beta^2 + A\alpha + B\beta + C & = & 0 \\
\alpha\beta + D\alpha + E\beta + F & = & 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$

for suitably defined scalar constants $A$,..., $F$. Further manipulation leads to a quartic equation.

My question: is there some "elegant" closed-form solution, or, otherwise, by what method could this be solved numerically (it seems there are two pairs of solutions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not "*really*" a quartic equation! Let me explain.

The first equation expands to
$$\alpha^2+(2p\cdot n) \alpha +p\cdot p=\beta^2+(2q\cdot n )\beta +q\cdot q=0.$$

The second equation expands to 
$$\alpha\beta+ (q\cdot n)\alpha +(p\cdot n)\beta +p \cdot q=0.$$

Complete the squares in the first equation.
We get something of shape
$$(\alpha +p\cdot n)^2-(\beta +q\cdot n)^2=A.$$

The second equation can be written as
$$(\alpha +p\cdot n)(\beta +q\cdot n)=B.$$

Let $x=\alpha+p\cdot n$ and $y=\beta +q\cdot n$.

Our system of equations  then becomes
$$x^2-y^2=A, \qquad xy=B.$$

So $y=B/x$. Substitute in the first equation, and multiply through by $x^2$.
We get a **quadratic** equation in $x^2$.  Solve this equation for $x^2$ in the usual way, then take the square roots.

Comment: That's brilliant... I wonder how you came up with this. Thanks!

Comment: There is very clear *symmetry*, so for general algebraic reasons, it is inevitable that there will be collapse. Then it was just a question of describing the collapse without fancy tools.